# C++ Code is giving an error that I can't understand:

Tags: c++

This code is a very simple extract from what I am really writing. But I am getting stuck on references and dereferencing. To explain this. NodeHandle stands in for a very large class from my framework. Arm is a class I am writing which should contain a reference to a NodeHandle. I want a variable globalArm to be of type Arm. Then in the main program I want to create a NodeHandle and I want to use setNodeHandle to store the reference to that NodeHandle into the Arm.

Here is the code that won't work as is. I've tried a lot of permutations. (p.s. ChatGPT is no help!)

```
#include <array>

class NodeHandle {
public:
    std::array<int, 10000> data;

    NodeHandle() {
        // Initialize the array to zero
        data.fill(0);
    }
};

class Arm {
public:
    NodeHandle* nodeHandle;

    Arm() : nodeHandle(nullptr) {}

    void setNodeHandle(NodeHandle& nh) {
        nodeHandle = &nh;
    }

};

// Global variable of type Arm
Arm globalArm;

int main() {
    // Allocate NodeHandle on the heap
    NodeHandle* nodeHandle = new NodeHandle();

    // Set the NodeHandle reference in globalArm
    globalArm.setNodeHandle(*nodeHandle);

    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and Link it I get this:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/gcc -fdiagnostics-color=always -g /Users/pitosalas/mydev/gpg_bran4/deleteme.cpp -o /Users/pitosalas/mydev/gpg_bran4/deleteme
ld: Undefined symbols:
  operator delete(void*), referenced from:
      _main in deleteme-907409.o
  operator new(unsigned long), referenced from:
      _main in deleteme-907409.o
  ___gxx_personality_v0, referenced from:
      /private/var/folders/g0/kks4z5dx6hbfhwvrw0zsgbn00000gn/T/deleteme-907409.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Build finished with error(s).
```

Comment: `error that I can't understand` ... is it invisible? ... you did not include it in your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you are compiling C++ code with GCC (C compiler). The **meaning of the error** is that GCC can not find `new` and `delete` operators during the linking phase, which is because GCC does not link to the C++ standard library by default.

When compiling your C++ file, replace `gcc` with `g++`. It should be:

```
/usr/bin/g++ -g /path/to/file.cpp -o /path/to/desired_name
```

I just tried your code sample with `g++`, and it works with no problems.

If this is a small example, and you want to apply changes to a bigger project, the compiler should be correctly set in the package/project's CMakeLists.txt file. Please let me know if my suggestion did not fix this issue.